# Parsing XML using XElement

Tags: xml, vb.net, xelement

I'm quite new to parsing XML using VB.NET. I have some XML in this format (simplified view)

```
<Range> 
<from>1</from> 
<to>5</to> 
</Range> 

<Range> 
<from>10</from> 
<to>20</to>
</Range>

<Range> 
<from>100</from> 
<to>200</to>
</Range>
```

There can be any amount of `<Range>` tags, but each Range tag will always have a `<from>` and `<to>` tag under it.

What I need to produce is a string, using the example above it will look something like this

```
1:1-5;2:10-20;3:100-200
```

I'm trying to use XElement to parse this, however not sure how to proceed. I tried iterating over using `.Descendants("Range")` which does give me the numbers but I can't separate out a from and to.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a `Range` element, you can get each of the sub elements by calling `.Element("from")` and `.Element("to")` on the range element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data select all  Range's and format.  I used System.Text.StringBuilder in the example below.

```
    'your test data
    smpl = <root>
               <Range>
                   <from>1</from>
                   <to>5</to>
               </Range>
               <Range>
                   <from>10</from>
                   <to>20</to>
               </Range>
               <Range>
                   <from>100</from>
                   <to>200</to>
               </Range>
           </root>

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim ct As Integer = 1
    For Each r As XElement In smpl...<Range>
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}:{1}-{2};", ct, r.<from>.Value, r.<to>.Value)
        ct += 1
    Next
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1)

    Dim s As String = sb.ToString
```

After running s =

```
 1:1-5;2:10-20;3:100-200
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, think I got a method although it is not clean!

I create 2 enumerators, one for `Descendants("from")` and another for `Descentants("to")`
Then, in a loop I can easily construct my string

Something like this (typing off memory, syntax might not be complete, txt is the XElement object for the entire XML)

```
Dim p as IEnumerable(of Xelement) = txt.Descendants("from")
Dim q as IEnumerable(of Xelement) = txt.Descendants("to")
Dim i as Integer = 0

While i < p.Count
String.Format("{0}:{1}-{2}", i.ToString,p(i),q(i))
End While
```